# What happens when I use vector with classes in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have class Person and create a Person type vector. I wanna know hat happens when I call a Person type function with index of vector. Does this store an object in array or what Please explain briefly thanks a lot in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Person
{
int age;
string name;
public:
Person(){};
void getdata()
{
    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    getline(cin >> ws, name);
    cout << "Enter your age: ";
    cin >> age;
}
void showdata()
{
    cout << "\nHello " << name << " your age is " << age;
}
};
void main()
{
vector<Person> myVector(3); 
unsigned int i = 0;
for (i; i < 3; i++)
    myVector[i].getdata();//Does this create & save an objects in that  location   Please explain briefly, Thanks
for (i=0; i < 3; i++)       //What if I do this like
                            /*for (i=0; i < 3; i++)
                                { Person p;
                                myVector.puskback(p); }
                                or what if I want a new data then what??*/

    myVector[i].showdata();
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)'s documentation. Happy reading.

Comment: No, `myVector` is allocated but its empty. It is similar to setting `vector<int> myVector(3);` and then expecting `myVector[1]` to return a meaningful value.

Comment: @romeric No, it isn't empty. It has three elements.

Comment: Of course, 3 elements are allocated, but they are not set to anything. They are zero at best. In the field of numerics these are called empty vectors. So `myVector[1]` does not segfault, but at the same time it does not return a meaningful value. That was my argument.

Comment: @romeric No, no and no. Please go read a C++ book. `myVector[1]`  contains a value constructed `Person` object.

Comment: @romeric: You're going to confuse a lot of people if, in the context of `std::vector`, you use a definition of `empty` which doesn't match up with the [`std::vector::empty`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/empty) member function.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley you are right! STL's definition of empty is different from most other vector libraries that I know of, for instance in Matlab, Python (numpy), Julia, heck even in Eigen which is a C++ library, empty stands for vectors whose elements are not set to anything.

Comment: If you intend to use vector with classes, I suggest you to read about and implement move constructor and move assignation operation. With theses implemented, the vector will optimize itself by moving data instead of copy it.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: His class already has a move constructor and move assignment operator, since he hasn't done anything to inhibit the compiler from adding them.

Comment: @romeric You will also confuse people by saying that `myVector[1]` does not return a meaningful value.

Comment: @romeric: I really don't think they do use a different definition. *You* just use a strange definition of "set to something". If an object is constructed, we generally consider it set to something. In this case, they are set to their default constructed value.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I believe we don't share the same terminology. Here, is the [standard definition of empty](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) in `numpy`.

Comment: @romeric: It appears so. However, even under the `numpy` definition, `vector<SomeType> myVector(3)` still does not qualify as empty, because the values are indeed initialized (even in the case of primitive types, like `int`, where they are initialized to zero).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Your example under `numpy` would be equivalent to `malloc` i.e. keeping the memory uninitialized. If you want to initialize to zero you would use `numpy.zero`. Not digressing from OP's question, in his case `myVector` of course  contains objects of `Person`. Any which way thanks for the discussion.

Comment: Well hmmm Thanks a lot guys can't say anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){}
    foo(){}
};
...
int main()
{
     std::vector<A> v1(3);
     //this creates a vector with 3 As by calling the empty constructor on each
     //means means you can readily manipulate these 3 As in v1
     for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
         v1[i].foo();

     std::vector<A> v2;
     //this creates a vector of As with no pre-instantiated As
     //you have to create As to add to the vector
     A a1;
     v2.push_back(a1);
     //you can now manipulate a1 in v2
     v2[0].foo(); 

     //You can add to v1 after having initially created it with 3 As
     A a2;
     v1.push_back(a2);

     //You have all the flexibility you need.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jafar helps a lot

Answer (score 4):

No, it does not create the object. All objects were created when your vector was created. What it does, it calls getdata() on already constructed object.
You can do pushback the way you suggested, and in this case you would like to create an empty vector initially (right now you are creating a vector with 3 elements)